# Need to get mac address tables from d-link switches with python

Tags: pysnmp

Probably  I should use SNMP v2c and pysnmp, but can't figure out how can I do that clearly, probably I need a list of port to mac array dictionaries. 
Anyways I am going to push that into mongodb and then get the port number having the mac address.

Here is the shell command that gives that information

```
snmpwalk -O0sUX -v2c -Cc -c public 10.77.10.8 BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbPort
```

update: https://github.com/edikmkoyan/portmatrix/blob/master/portmatrix.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest starting from a script like this. It's not debugged, so if you get it fixed to a fully working condition - please comment and I'd update the code to benefit others.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBindTable) in bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData('public'),
                              UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
                              ContextData(),
                              0, 25,
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('BRIDGE-MIB', 'dot1dTpFdbPort')),
                              lexicographicMode=False):
    if errorIndication:
        Exception(errorIndication)
    elif errorStatus:
        Exception(errorStatus)
    else:
        for varBinds in varBindTable:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                # imaginary MongoDB document mapping port-ID -> MAC
                db.portsAndMacs.insert_one(
                    {varBind[1].prettyPrint(): varBind[0].prettyPrint()[-17:]}
                )
```

Comment: where is varBindTable defined?

Comment: Starting from if blocks you should add indent on each line, and remove this line.
    for varBinds in varBindTable:

Comment: and it actually start from the dot1dTpFdbPort but walks all BRIDGE-MIB subtree.

Comment: Updated my code. Sorry for confusion! The lexicographicMode flag might help fetching just the subtrees.

Comment: with this print varBind it prints out this BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbPort.c8:2a:14:0b:23:35 = 134

but with this it prints out something like this 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2.168.32.102.9.136.105

the JSON is crafted incorrectly

Comment: I guess you should also remove this line for varBinds in varBindTable:
varBindTables is not defined

Comment: also lookupMib should be True

Comment: give me your email so I can add you to contributors list https://github.com/edikmkoyan/portmatrix/blob/master/portmatrix.py

Comment: Added you as a collaborator, Ilya I can't get the mac address table for D-Link DGS-3120, maybe there is a way to do something generic?
D-Link DGS-3120 does not have OID for BRIDGE-MIB.

Comment: Try walking the whole device to see if there is something 6-octet long there. The other way would be to read/grep all published D-LINK MIBs in hope to figure out where they conventionally keep L2 addresses. But chances are they do not show MACs via SNMP at all.